# Manually collapsing kendo scheduler view bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am having trouble finding how I can collapse this thing manually. The kendo scheduler collapses it automatically at 1025px at the moment. But my view bar has more views than the typical example... so this causes it to make a new line in the header until collapses, which doesn't look great... I want it to collapse at 1455px.

I tried to inspect the page, but nothing seems to happen when the view bar collapses. No classes are added to the element that is the view bar, nothing about it really changes. I am assuming it is just handled in the JS kendo.all.js somewhere, but it is an enormous file and didn't really know what to look for.

Any assistance on finding out how to collapse this thing manually when I want would be appreciated!